# Detecting type of webservice in httpmodule

Tags: .net, dependency-injection, httpmodule

Is there any way to detect the type of a webservice inside a httpmodule?
The reason for this is that I want to do some property injection to the webservice before
it's processed.

I found this:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/asmxandxml/thread/0e848eee-d353-4e67-b47f-89fddb600009

but that is one h..l of an ugly solution.

Anyone have a nice solution?

Comment: Are you currently using a DI framework?

Comment: I have my own-brew one, but as far as I have search I can't find one that is able to inject dependencies into webservices.

Comment: Autofac Web integration module is doing property injection on ASP.Net Pages, possibly this framework could be extended to do the same for web services. Just taken a quick glance at the source and it looks feasible.

Comment: To inject on aspx-pages is a piece of cake, but webservices from ajax-calls is an whole other story, check my link above.

Comment: checked out the discussion now, and ouch, does not look nice. But I cannot see how they solved it there either because they create a new instance of the web service type...guess this really *is* trickier than I expected :)